# How to decrypt text when four first letters of the key are missing in Facebook CTF contest?

Tags: encryption, c, ctf

I am beginner in cyber security. Now I am participating on Facebook Catch the Flag contest. I have to solve following task:

There is a key. But the first four characters of the key are missing:

```
_ _ _ _ U3xn3Gk9y
```

This is the algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fi, *fo, *fk;
    int i, r;
    char key[20], text[100];

    fi = fopen("flag.txt", "r");
    fo = fopen("encrypted.txt", "w");
    fk = fopen("key.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fi, "%s", text);
    fscanf(fk, "%s", key);



    srand(key[0] * key[1] * key[2] * key[3]);
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(text); ++i)
    {
        r = rand();
        putc(r ^ key[(r % strlen(key))] ^ text[i], fo);
    }

    fclose(fi);
    fclose(fo);
    fclose(fk);
    return 0;
}
```

Encrypted text:

> РY‘ґЊЈZц‚…Jщ,PvPw#ѓЗfыbаЁ+dИ?ѕцiЃyЛSBШ“¦ЕiЈ;иb—щьХЗ*]ЋOЛ,O™µEкЧи–ББш}

I need to decypher the ecrypted text.

First of all, I am not asking for solution or answer. I am asking for some hints:

1. From where should I start to solve: to find first 4 characters of key or random number?
2. How does `rand()` algorithm work?
3. If `r ^ key[(r % strlen(key))] ^ text[i] = encrypted[i]` is true, what will be formula for `text[i]=`?
4. Is there any mathematical way to solve this problem? If there is could you name it?
5. Could you give any hint (not solution) to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you basically need to bruteforce the last 4 characters of the key. Given the rest of the key it looks like alpha numeric those characters probably are too.

As to the working of rand(), this is implementation dependant and just means can I have a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1, and srand is used to seed it. Now this means it will give the same order of numbers with a given seed assuming the same implementation. Did they say it is to be compiled with GCC against GCC libraries and executed on a Linux machine or anything?

Comment: Oh, should be worth noting, algorithm is not secure in any way as pseudo-random number generators being used are not secure, rand() is for simulations rather than secure RNG generation.

Comment: Oh, and cipher is symetric. Just switch encrypted and decrypted to reverse.

Comment: Do you have a link to the CTF? I couldn't find it online, looks like fun.

Comment: I'm down-voting because this is not a question at all. Or better said, it's a question with no answer, as you are asking for hints. Alice can have some hints and Bob other hints, which of both answer is correct? Neither.

Comment: This question specifically asks for a mathematical solution, that is not opinion based. Even asking for hints can be a good question

Comment: @ewanm89, thank you for your suggestion. I will try to bruteforce, however, 62*62*62*62=14776336. Is not this big?) Anyways I will try this. I think I will check decrypted text for alfanumeric characters. What do you think about this?

Comment: I found that if r ^ key[(r % strlen(key))] ^ text[i] = encrypted[i] is true, so text[i]=r ^ key[(r % strlen(key))] ^ encrypted[i] is also true. for example 0^1^0=1 => 0^1^1=0

Comment: @Ayozint, I know this question can not be answered. I tried to solve this problem for one day, but unfortunately could not solve. I had no idea where I can ask this question, so I came here. From the side, it would be unfair to ask answer/solution, while others are trying to solve it themselves. I hope for your understanding)

Comment: @Polynomial, here is the link: https://195.158.2.203/

Comment: So Facebook is hosting a CTF contest on a server from Uzbekistan?

Comment: @bayo15 to me it looks like someone else is hosting the Facebook CTF that was openly released a couple of weeks ago :)

Comment: @GayratRakhimov depends on hardware, 4 characters is easily bruteforcable with a little bit of processing power behind it. CPUs can hit millions of tests a second, and GPUs can do billions.

Answer (score 4):

A few hints:

1. The letters in the key are likely to be within the ASCII printable range.
2. The decoded text is likely within the ASCII printable range.
3. It's not very hard to bruteforce a 32-bit number, even less hard if you can reduce the key space down.

Comment: Given rest of the known key are within alphanumeric range rather I would probably just try that first before adding in the rest of the printable range.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can brute force this rather quickly, but in case you are curious, you don't need to brute force this entire solution. There is a mathematical approach.
You might even require pieces of this anyway since this seems to be a hashing algorithm and not an encryption algorithm (I.e. it is not reliably reversible).

Does it  make you curious that a repeatable encryption algorithm uses random number generation? That can only work when the random seed (look up `srand`) is set consistently for the same input, meaning consecutive calls to `rand()` will return the same ordered sequence of results.

Q. How is the random seed set in this case?

A. By the product of the character codes of the first four characters, the ones that happen to be missing.

We know from the code that the resulting encrypted text will have the same length as the plaintext input. We also know that each encrypted output character is generated by the original character at its index like this:
`(random number generated from the seed at the n'th pass where n is the current index + 1) ^ (that same random number mod the key length of 13 in your example) ^ (the character code at the current index)`.

From that you can derive a simple mathematical formula to find `r` at a given pass through encryption based on an output character code and index.

I couldn't find an official source for free, but several places like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768180/rand-implementation) show how the c `rand` function is implemented:

```
static unsigned long int next = 1;

int rand(void) // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}
```

Notice that the seed is adjusted each time a number is generated. You can build another formula based on the `rand` implementation to find what possible values `next` can when `rand` returns the character code associated with the 5th character of the output (the first one associated with a key character that you know). Take each of those possibilities and filter them down by running subsequent passes through `rand` based on the code above and the encryption code using the `rand` output as the `r` value and checking the results against the next characters of the output until you are left with only a single valid possible option for `next` at the 5th pass.

Once you know that, reverse that one time for each of the previous characters to get the first 4 values of `r`. Once you have solved for those values of `r`, all that's left is to reverse `output[i] = r ^ key[(r % strlen(key))] ^ text[i]` to solve for `text[i]`. It will be useful to recall that the inverse of `y = a ^ x` is `y = log base a (x)`. Plug in the `r` values you solved for previously in the right order to get the character codes associated with that pass through the encryption. Add those to the beginning of the key and check your work by reversing the encryption algorithm and passing in your new key with the encrypted text and seeing if the output makes sense. If it does, you've completed the challenge without brute force (except perhaps in your filtering).

Of course, since the key space is small enough to bruteforce, you can always do that.